# How to start Oracleserciceorcl if it not available in services.msc

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm getting

> ora-12560: TNS:Protocol Adapter Error

while trying to lo-gin to Oracle 11g. I did not find OracleServiceORCL file in services.msc. How to start this service? Please help me.

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons for that error to be raised. 1) Is there no OracleServise<SID> at all or is it just OracleServiceORCL that is missing? 2) You installed Oracle **software** only, without creating a database(at this stage `DBCA` calls `oradim` utility and creates an `OracleServise<SID>`);  3) Maybe the windows registry key `HKLM\system\ControlSet\Services\OracleService<SID>` has been deleted. You've provided not that much information.

Answer (score 6):

Try ORADIM -NEW -SID ORCL

As far as i know this won't create a problem. If the service is already available it will throw error.

Comment: Try it where? What do I do with this?

Comment: run the command prompt as administrator and execute it. running in any specific location is not required